# Add a new field in a already created feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, error, feature-class

I have a feature class. On the basis of some calculation, I want to create a new field in that table and set value of that field. To do so, my algorithm is:

```
void UpdateFeatureClass(IFeatureClass featureClass, List<Edge> edges)
{
    CreateField(featureClass);
    UpdateDictionary(featureClass);
    UpdateFieldValue(edges);
}
```

To add a field I use following code snippet:

```
private void CreateField(IFeatureClass featureClass)
{
    IFields oldFields = featureClass.Fields;
    IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)oldFields;

    IField field = new FieldClass();
    var fieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)field;
    fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Value";
    fieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeInteger;
    fieldsEdit.AddField(field);
}
```

Update dictionary basically creates a dictionary with all features of the feature class. The key of the dictionary is feature's OID and value of the dictionary is the feature. After that I am trying to update features with value in the value field. The code snippet is:

```
private void UpdateFieldValue(List<Edge> edges)
{
    int fieldIndex = dictionary[0].Fields.FindField("Value");
    if (fieldIndex != -1)
    {
        foreach (Edge edge in edges)
        {
            var feature = _dictionary[edge.PolylineEdge.OID];
            feature.set_Value(fieldIndex, edge.Value);
            feature.Store();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for me except the feature.Store() command. Whenever this line executes, `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'` exception occurs. From my perspective, if there is any problem with set value, the error should occur in that statement. I couldn't find out any pointer why the store command creates the error. Can anyone please help me to find why the error is occurring?

**EDIT :** 
I tried to store value in different fields of the feature and succeeded. Only updating the value of the newly created field, gives the exception.

- Error message: "Error encoding INFO item during save"
- Error code: (-2147220133)

**EDIT :** 
I think the problem is the newly created field is not permanent. after adding the field, I go through the feature class and the newly created field is here. But whenever I close the ArcMap and open a new ArcMap, I find that the newly added field is vanished. So, I think the problem is the change is not permanent. So, My question is **how to create a field in a already created feature class permanently?**

Thanks

Comment: Is your feature class a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class?

Comment: @artwork21: It is a shapefile

Comment: To debug it I would first hard-code the feature.set_Value statement to always set a specific value to (maybe) a specific field and take it from there.

Comment: @mapoholic: I tried to set value in different fields and store features, there was no exceptions. But when I set value in the newly created field and store the feature, the exception occurred

Comment: is edge.Value an integer?

Comment: @vinayan: Yes, it is a integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [`IFieldsEdit`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000368000000):

> The **IFieldsEdit** interface is used when creating a fields collection. You cannot use it to insert or delete a field from a fields collection belonging to an existing table. To add a field to an existing object class, use the **IClass::AddField** method.  To remove a field from an existing object class, use the **IClass::DeleteField** method.

So either use [`IClass.AddField`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddField_Method/0025000000vp000000/) or the geoprocessor to do it.

For better performance consider using [`IGeoDatabaseBridge.GetFeatures`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetFeatures_Method/00250000039n000000/) which returns a cursor given a set of Object IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Actually I already tried IClass.AddField method and succeeded.

Comment: I am using `var featureCursor = featureClass.Search(null, false);` for getting all features. Does `IGeoDatabaseBridge.GetFeatures` better perform than that?

Comment: GetFeatures is used when you already have a set of Object IDs. Since you are using a non-recycling cursor to save a reference to each feature, you might get better performance if you were to instead use a recycling cursor to save each Object ID instead of an IFeature, and subsequently use GetFeatures with the ObjectIDs you need to update the features. I am only guessing, but I think this would be more efficient.

Comment: `IClass.AddField` method adds field in a shape file perfectly, but whenever I am working with any geodatabase feature class, `IClass.AddField` method gives error: *Cannot acquire a schema lock because of an existing lock.*

Answer (score 3):

To create a new field I think you need to have a schema lock first ([ISchemaLock](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISchemaLock_Interface/0025000007z9000000/))

From the example [in here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000003z5000000.htm):

```
public void AddFieldToFeatureClass(IFeatureClass featureClass, IField field)
{
    ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)featureClass;

    try
    {
        // A try block is necessary, as an exclusive lock might not be available.
        schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);

        // Add the field.
        featureClass.AddField(field);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Handle appropriately for your application.
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Set the lock to shared, whether or not an error occurred.
        schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
    }
}
```